# typescript, cómo checkear tipado asociado a array

Tags: typescript

¿Existe alguna forma de comprobar el tipado de forma similar a esto?

```
interface People {
    name: string;
    groups: string[] | number[];
};

let test: number[];

const values: People = {
    name: 'nameTest',
    groups: [7,8,9],
};
if (values.groups instanceof number[]) {
    test = [...values.groups];   //- devuelve error de tipado
}
```

El error que me devuelve es el siguiente:

Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Pero el tipado se supone que lo comprueba justo encima.

Comment: Estás declarando tu variable `test` como un Array numérico pero luego tratas de establecer un valor mixto, es decir, el valor de `groups` puede ser de tipo Array numérico o de Array de strings, de allí el error.

Comment: *Pero el tipado se supone que lo comprueba justo encima.* En la sentencia `if` estás preguntando si el valor de `groups` es de tipo Array numérico y por supuesto lo es, podrías preguntar si es de Array de strings y también entrará en la condición. Te sugiero que leas un poco sobre [*Conditional Type*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), de esta forma podrías establecer el valor y el tipo de tu variable `test` correctamente. Saludos

Comment: Entiendo que puede llegar a cumplir las dos condiciones pero entonces significa que no se puede trabajar con los datos de dentro por no saber si es string o number, ¿no?

Si en vez de ser el caso de number[] o string[] fuese OptionalEffectTiming y ComputedEffectTiming, ¿cómo puedo saber qué métodos usar si no conozco el tipado de lo que llega? Es que en la documentación de typescript no he conseguido encontrar cómo distinguir estos casos a pesar de que se permiten y me encuentro perdido.

Comment: **Problemas detectados**:
-instanceof sirve para ver si el prototipo del constructor aparece y compararlo, por lo que no se puede hacer con number[] o con string[]
-otro error puede estar con las funciones de every y filter, ya que pueden dar un error de "predicado no llamable" por lo que crearse un tipo intermedio solucionaría el problema:
`type Mixto = string | number;
interface People {
    name: string;
    groups: Mixto[];
};`

Comment: **Solución**:
Realmente typescript no sabe si el array es un number[] o string[]. Por lo que hay que verificar todos los elementos uno a uno, por ejemplo con esta forma:
`if (Array.isArray(values.groups) && values.groups.every((value) => typeof value === 'number')) {
    test = values.groups as number[];
}`
otra forma similar podría ser:
`test = values.groups.filter((item)=>typeof item === "number");`

Solución encontrada en [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)